# Create a new entity in Azure cosmosDB Table API using postman

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

I am able to get the list of collection from my cosmosdb by postan via api like: https://mycosmosdburl/dbs/TablesDB/colls
I get the list, but I am not able to find end point for creating a new entry in my table.

When I try to post my entry in the body in JSON format to the endpoint:
https://mycosmosdburldbs/TablesDB/colls/mytable/
Then I get the error:

> {
> "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
> "message": "RequestHandler.Post"
> }

I can find lots of examples doing this using different SKDs but I need to create new entity in table using API only, as I have to put this in my Azure API Management policy.

Comment: You need to use the `https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs` endpoint as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/create-a-document . Why would APIM stop you from using the SDK?

Comment: I am trying to save the data of request body in CosmosDB within <inbound> tag of APIM policy. Have not seen any SDK usage there, not sure if that would work. Trying to avoid the Azure function for same.